# Gym preventing socket from connecting

Tags: python, sockets, openai-gym

(using gym 0.23.1, although I've tried other versions)

I've got a custom gym environment, torille. When initialized, this launches a copy of toribash.exe, and opens a socket to listen to connect to the toribash instance. I'm running this in WSL inside of windows. Toribash is launching from linux using wine.

Here is the code (it has been slightly abreviated):

```py
    def init(self):
        """
        Actual init: Launch the game process, wait for connection and
        and settings for the first game
        """
        # Use global filelock to avoid mixing up Toribash instances with
        # corresponding Python scripts if we have multiple Toribashes running.
        # Create lock here to make code pickle-able before call to init.
        init_lock = FileLock(self.lock_file,
                             timeout=constants.TIMEOUT)
        print('PORT',self.port)
        with init_lock:
            if sys.platform == "linux":
                # Sanity check launching on Linux
                utils.check_linux_sanity()
                # Attempt to make stderr.txt read-only
                # TODO this will cause headache when trying to remove torille
                _ = utils.set_file_readonly(self.toribash_stderr_file)
                # Add wine command explicitly for running on Linux
                self.process = subprocess.Popen((
                    "nohup", "wine", self.executable_path),
                    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
                pid = self.process.pid
                import psutil 
                p = psutil.Process(pid)
            else:
                # Launch on Windows (just call the .exe)
                # Don't try to set stderr.txt to read-only: This will
                # cause Toribash to crash on Windows
                self.process = subprocess.Popen((self.executable_path,),
                                                stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                                                stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
            # Create socket for waiting for Toribash to connect
            import time
            time.sleep(2)
            s = socket.socket()

            # This allows rebinding to same address multiple times on *nix
            # Otherwise you will get "address in use" if you launch multiple
            # Toribash instances on same computer
            # From Stackoverflow #6380057
            #print({'SOL_SOCKET':socket.SOL_SOCKET, 'SO_REUSEADDR':socket.SO_REUSEADDR })
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            s.bind(("", self.port))
            #s.settimeout(constants.TIMEOUT)
            s.settimeout(30)
            s.listen(1)
            print(s)
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print(addr)
            # Close the listener socket
            print(p.connections())
            s.close()
```

When I call the following code, it works normally.

```py
    from torille import ToribashControl
    toribash = ToribashControl(draw_game=True)
    toribash.init()
```

This gives the following output:

```
PORT 7788
<socket.socket fd=63, family=2, type=1, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 7788)>
('127.0.0.1', 33622)
[pconn(fd=29, family=<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, type=<SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, laddr=addr(ip='127.0.0.1', port=33622), raddr=addr(ip='127.0.0.1', port=7788), status='ESTABLISHED')]
```

Here is the weird part, if you create it as a gym environment and try to reset it, the socket no longer is connected to and it times out. Gym's environment reset calls the above function, so I'm not sure why it behaves differently. The parameters appear to be the same.

```py
import gym
import torille.envs
env = gym.make("Toribash-DestroyUke-v2")
env.set_draw_game(True)
initial_state = env.reset()
```

When I run this code, the subprocess is started, and I get this output:

```
PORT 7788
<socket.socket fd=65, family=2, type=1, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 7788)>
```

and then the `s.accept()` times out.

My understanding of what is happening here is then when `Init` is called via gym, the subprocess that is created doesn't connect to the listener.

However, the workaround I have come up with is to create a separate subprocess, and then try to reset the gym environment, which works. What I assume is happening here is that there are two instances of Toribash running. The one created manual is able to connect to the listener, and the one created inside `Init` (from the `env.reset()` call) cannot.

I'm still trying to figure out how Toribash.exe knows where to connect to the listener, as that doesn't seem to be specified anywhere. If I had to guess the issue, the default config in the gym call somehow tries to make Toribash connect to a different/address or port.

Ultimately, my work around only works in testing, and I'm going to need to fix this long term.